# How can I add cross references in an existing PDF file?

Tags: linux, pdf, hyperlink, cross-reference

I have a PDF document that I am reading on my computer running Ubuntu 20.04. The document has over 200 references but, unfortunately, none of the citations of these references are clickable, e.g:

```
Lorem epsum Quo veritatis tempora asperiores [35] soluta id. Ea similique culpa iusto deleniti rerum vel et. Atque illum sunt voluptate
```

The reference [35] is not clickable.

My question: What are some tools (preferably open source) that will allow me to create cross-references so in the example above it will allow me to create a hyperlink from [35] to the corresponding reference item in References list (at the end of the document).

Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: Manually, you would use a good PDF editor (such as Acrobat). With the Link tool, you can create those cross references.

Comment: @MaxWyss: Adobe Acrobat is not available in Linux. I found PDF-Xchange editor to be the best alternative because it runs under Wine. but it's not free.

Comment: PDF-Xchange (Pro) is a viable PDF tool.

Answer (score -1):

PDF-XChange Editor is indeed free, and it ewasily makes cross-reference links in the way you describe.

There is a pro version, but the free version has, per the web site, about 70% of all the functions of the pro version, and the links are in the free version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).